# How do I perform a multi-segment FTP download with ftplib Python 2.7?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

Complete noob to Python, but I have done simple FTP downloads and uploads that write out chunks to disk instead of filling RAM before writing the whole file.

My question is, how do I download a file in x amount of parts simultaneously (multiple threads downloading different segments of a single file) while writing it to disk immediately instead of filling RAM first?

I have looked around for examples of this, but they fill RAM first then write out the file.

Also I was wondering if it is even possible to do this for upload?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out myself :)

```
from ftplib import *
from threading import *
from shutil import *
import os

num_parts = 20
FTP_server = 'ftp.example.com'
FTP_user = 'mark'
FTP_password = 'password'

FTP_directory = '/foo/bar'
FTP_file = 'foo.bar'


class Done(Exception):
    pass


def open_ftp():
    ftp = FTP(FTP_server, FTP_user, FTP_password)
    ftp.cwd(FTP_directory)
    return ftp


def go():
    ftp = open_ftp()
    filesize = ftp.size(FTP_file)
    print 'filesize: ' + str(filesize)
    ftp.quit()

    chunk_size = filesize/num_parts
    last_chunk_size = filesize - (chunk_size * (num_parts - 1))

    downloaders = []
    for i in range(num_parts):
        if i == (num_parts - 1):
            this_chunk_size = last_chunk_size
        else:
            this_chunk_size = chunk_size
        downloaders.append(Downloader(i, chunk_size * i, this_chunk_size))
    for downloader in downloaders:
        downloader.thread.join()

    with open(FTP_file, 'w+b') as f:
        for downloader in downloaders:
            copyfileobj(open(downloader.part_name, 'rb'), f)


class Downloader:

    thread_number = 0

    def __init__(self, part_number, part_start, part_size):
        self.filename = FTP_file
        self.part_number = part_number
        self.part_name = 'part' + str(self.part_number)
        self.part_start = part_start
        self.part_size = part_size
        Downloader.thread_number += 1
        self.thread_number = Downloader.thread_number
        self.ftp = open_ftp()
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.receive_thread)
        self.thread.start()

    def receive_thread(self):
        try:
            self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+self.filename, self.on_data, 100000, self.part_start)
        except Done:
            pass

    def on_data(self, data):
        with open(self.part_name, 'a+b') as f:
            f.write(data)
        if os.path.getsize(self.part_name) >= self.part_size:
            with open(self.part_name, 'r+b') as f:
                f.truncate(self.part_size)
            raise Done

go()
```

So I learned that callback from retrbinary is the actual binary data that it gets. So for each thread, I make a file and append that binary data from the callback to it until the size of the file is greater than the expected size, then we truncate the extra.
When all threads are complete, the files are concatenated and a file with the original filename is produced. Filesize and sha256 were done and confiremd it works. :)

The code was adapted from [RichieHindle](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21664046/Writing-an-FTP-Client-Multiple-Downloads-and-Multipart-Downloads.html)

Comment: For a large file I see the following error

  File "/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 555, in size
    resp = self.sendcmd('SIZE ' + filename)
  File "/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 550 foo.tgz: too large for type A SIZE.

How do I work around this problem? ftp.sendcmd('binary') does not work

Comment: @gostkadost the error that is raised is to do with permissions (550), make sure you are giving it the correct path.

Comment: @MarkPashmfouroush - I was trying to use this same methodology but got to know that the FTP server I am working on is not configured for SIZE (ftplib.error_perm: 501 command aborted -- FTP server not configured for SIZE). Do you have any workaround for this?